# building AAR in Android Studio

Tags: android, gradle, aar

It's my first time building AAR

The official site says that All I hate to do is build APK and AAR will be assembled

Here's the quote:

[image]

But when I choose "Build Apk(s)" nothing happens.

Another tutorial says I have to choose Gradle-> library name -> tasks-> build->  `:assembleRelease`.

But there is no such thing :

[image]

How can I assemble library as AAR?

here's my gradle :

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.library'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.2'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
    def room_version = "2.2.3"
    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
    kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"
    implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:$room_version"
    implementation "androidx.room:room-rxjava2:$room_version"
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just click `assemble` or add `buildTypes.debug`. While you don't have `buildTypes.debug` defined, it won't generate the tasks you are looking for (as there only is one configuration present there and so there is nothing to tell apart).

Comment: assemble says "BUILD SUCCESSFUL" and build library doesn't have aar in it

Comment: It should not have an AAR in it, but should result in an AAR. There is no other task to build.

Comment: to what dir? "build" dir doesn't have it